# The UIButton works fine at first run, but doesn't work at the second run on the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, xcode7

I have been trying to make this basic app. I added segue to the main view controller. In the segue, I added a button that will play a video on button click. 
The button works completely fine at the initial run of the simulator, but when I run the app again, after adding constraints, the button disappears and all I can see is text written on the button. Also, I did not even connect the button using IBAction or IBoutlet.

Constraints:

[image: constraints screenshot]

With Constraints:

[image: simulator screenshot]

Comment: Both pictures are the same.  Did you accidentally upload the same picture twice?

Comment: An actual screenshot with your constraints will be much more useful than the screenshots with/without the button on the screen.

Comment: Problem in leading and trailing constraints constants. You put 131 on both of them and its a lot. Try to set a constant that optimized for all device sizes or just make button centered with or without fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to keep the button in the center of the screen, use the Alignment Constraints and make both centre vertically and horizontally.

[image]

In case you want to place it anywhere else, then only adding the leadingConstraint and the topConstraint is more than enough.